# Could we consider making "1 new answer has been posted" configurable through prefs?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I've noticed a trend in how I answer questions lately, and I don't like that it bothers me, but I think I'm going to post this and see if anyone else feels the same way.

When I'm answering a question, if I see the "1 new answer has been posted" banner come up, I feel defeated. I will occasionally stop answering and leave that question, because I feel it's some bizarre race against time, and I don't like feeling that type of pressure when I'm trying to answer a question. I usually do this in my spare time, I found it to be a relaxing activity before that new answer banner came along.

I know this might sound silly, but I've been surprised to find that it really bothers me. I'd be surprised if it doesn't bother anyone else.

Can we consider making it configurable on the Prefs panel?

---

**Edit:**
After reading the answers I've gotten so far, I see the value in the feature. I still feel a bit bothered by it, but I feel less... against it. It'd be nice if it could be configurable, but I can also see that possibly detracting from the SO experience.

Comment: I know exactly how you feel. It bothers me too. But hasn't that banner been there right from the beginning?

Comment: I don't remember it being there for the first few months, but my memory isn't so great on this particular SO feature :-)

Comment: As far as I recall this has been here since the beginning. It was implemented during the beta stages of SO.

Comment: Yeah, I do remember it being around since beta, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, first time I've ever seen someone come out **against** this feature.

It's there so you can load the new answers as you type and not have to waste your time writing a duplicate answer.

Comment: To be fair, I didn't realize you could load the new answers as you type - I'll have to see how that works next time I'm in that situation. I do like that it helps prevent duplicates, too, although I personally would rather spend the time crafting a good answer that I come up with rather than trying to find a different angle from other posters, or trying to finish answering quickly, or something of that nature...  but that's just me.

Answer (score 2):

Hell No.

This is the only way I get an opportunity to determine whether answering is at all worthwhile. Sometimes it can be demotivating, but load the answers, read them, and if yours is till right or valid finish answering. If not, vote for the correct one and move on.

Not all of us **have** to be Jon Skeet.

Comment: I personally don't see how the rate of answering a question correlates to that question's actual worth. What if it's simply a slow time of the day, or a Sunday, or something?

Comment: I have to admit that went way over my head. If it's a slow day changes are you will be the only one answering. The fastest gun in the west has often been discussed already?

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen that discussion, I'll have to look at it.

Comment: Even with the amended question I still stand by my answer.

Comment: Fair enough :-) I see your point, I think I'd just prefer if it didn't have to feel so demotivating at times. It makes me wonder how many other really good answers we might be missing out on.

Answer (score 1):

Hell No.

Seeing this banner gives me the additional incentive to answer the question in the best way I can, adding related material and rewriting my answer for clarity, in order to to get on top of the early but incomplete response.

Comment: I guess that "additional incentive" is exactly what the OP calls "preasure". And that's why he's been generous enough to suggest to make the banner optional.

Answer (score 1):

The banner is part of the rush to the head. A Q&A equivalent of a typing game where you're gunning down zombies and the walking dead with a shot gun that never empties. Flex your brain, your fingers and get better and quicker.

It's not to discourage you to stop posting, but to encourage you to take a shot of chocolate milk when you've been gunned down. Play it that way, pretty soon, if you're on the site trying to answer when the steenking Amehdicans are up for their business day, you'll be upchucking a not-crunchy milkshake in no time.

The notification banner of "Head to the toilet, it's time to wallow" has been there for a while. It's probably that you've been answering at slow times that you haven't seen it. Or that you've posted just before the polling was done to tip you off.

Comment: "but to encourage you to take a shot of chocolate milk when you've been gunned down" - I was not expecting a sentence like that to appear in this discussion at all, haha, kudos, my friend, kudos.

Comment: I think what I'm uncomfortable with is the rush itself; not everyone is good at answering in a rushed situation. I personally don't think SO should feel like an exam, I think it should feel a bit less high-stakes, and more like a professional exchange where taking the time to answer in the best way possible is encouraged. But that's just my view, I'm personally not so quick on my feet under pressure, and I think when it comes to me givng a quality answer, I work better when I don't have that extra pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SOFU is not the right place for you. Do not produce duplicates, they are annoying and get downvoted. Fell free to be shot again by Jon Skeet!